# crm resource cleanup command in pcs?

Tags: pacemaker, crm, corosync

Is there an alternative command for `crm resource cleanup <rsc>` in the pacemaker configuration system? I got the following error message from pcs status and I found on different sites, that a `crm resource cleanup <rsc>` would solve the problem. If there is no alternative command, is there another way to bring up the resource correct?

```
OS: CentOS 6.4 x86_64

Kernel: 2.6.32

pcs version: 0.9.26
```

**pcs status:**

```
Stack: classic openais (with plugin)
Current DC: drbd1 - partition with quorum
Version: 1.1.8-7.el6-394e906
2 Nodes configured, 2 expected votes
5 Resources configured.

Online: [ drbd1 drbd2 ]

Full list of resources:

Master/Slave Set: master_drbd [drbd_r0]
    Masters: [ drbd1 ]
    Slaves: [ drbd2 ]
Resource Group: iSCSI_Group
  ClusterIP   (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):        Started drbd1
iSCSI_Target  (ocf::heartbeat:iSCSITarget):    Started drbd2
iSCSI_LUN1    (ocf::heartbeat:iSCSILogicalUnit):       Stopped

Failed actions:
iSCSI_LUN1_start_0 (node=drbd2, call=42, rc=1, status=complete): unknown error
iSCSI_LUN1_start_0 (node=drbd1, call=42, rc=1, status=complete): unknown error
```

**pcs resource show --all:**

```
Master: master_drbd
  Resource: drbd_r0 (provider=linbit type=drbd class=ocf)
    Attributes: drbd_resource=r0 interval=10s
Group: iSCSI_Group
  Resource: ClusterIP (provider=heartbeat type=IPaddr2 class=ocf)
    Attributes: ip=192.168.10.105 cidr_netmask=24
    Operations: monitor interval=10s
  Resource: iSCSI_Target (provider=heartbeat type=iSCSITarget class=ocf)
    Attributes: iqn=iqn.2013-10.localdomain:storage.localdomain tid=1
    Operations: monitor interval=10s
  Resource: iSCSI_LUN1 (provider=heartbeat type=iSCSILogicalUnit class=ocf)
    Attributes: target_iqn=iqn.2013-10.localdomain:storage.localdomain lun=1 path=/dev/drbd1
    Operations: monitor interval=10s
```

Please advise, thanks!

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=912528

Comment: I solved my problem!

After I couldn't find anything I just deleted all my resources and constraints. Then I rebooted and created all resources and constraints again, and now it works! strange.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but this is the solution: `pcs resource cleanup iSCSI_LUN1`

Comment: the correct command is pcs resource cleanup iSCSI_LUN1 , you need to omit the action